# Woocommerce redirect after add-to-cart error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have being doing research for a few days but still cannot find an answer.

I am using Woocommerce without the Single Product page. So I am using urls like http://domain.com/?add-to-cart=ID to add products to cart.

My products are sold individually which means that I can only add the product to cart once. Now when I add a product for the first time, I am redirected to the cart page which is what I wanted. However, when I add the product the second time, it is refreshing the page I am on. But I want to be redirected to the cart page and shown the error message like 'You cannot add the product twice' on the **cart page**.

When I was reading the Woocommerce core source code, I found the code below in the ***add-to-cart()*** function in file ***class-wc-ajax.php***.

```
// If there was an error adding to the cart, redirect to the product page to show any errors
        $data = array(
            'error'       => true,
            'product_url' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink( $product_id ), $product_id )
        );

        wp_send_json( $data );
```

So I tried to add a filter by adding the code below in my theme ***functions.php*** file.

```
function filter_woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error($redirect, $product_id) {
  $redirect = esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() );
  return $redirect;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', 10, 2 );
```

But nothing was changed.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: in your function before `$redirect` try to add `global $woocommerce;`

Comment: URL should be: domain.com/cart/?add-to-cart=243

Answer (score 2):

This is the default option that is build into WooCommerce. You can find the option in the WooCommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Display area. When the option “Redirect to the cart page after successful addition” is checked it will redirect all users to the cart after adding a product to the cart.
Follow this

[image]

You can redirect to cart page when you get error

```
 function firefog_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {
        $url = WC()->cart->get_cart_url();
        return $url;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', 'firefog_custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

You can also use to redirect to checkout page

```
function firefog_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {
    $url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'firefog_custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the your code. Redirection to check worked but redirection after error didn't seem to work for me. I came up with an easy solution, which is using http://domain.com/cart/?add-to-cart=ID to add a product to cart. In this way, even there is an error, you will still land on the cart page.

Comment: You didn't read the full answer. he has given all the code. For me, `woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error` filter worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issue,and checking the console I saw that WordPress was returning a 404 error for the page /shop/?add-to-cart=ID...  Manage to get it working properly by adding a 404.php file that has a conditional statement that if the page url = /shop/?add-to-car=ID redirect to checkout, if not display the normal 404 page.

```
   <?php
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
      //change "ID" to your product id number (example:/shop/?add-to-cart=22 )
    if($url==="/shop/?add-to-cart=ID"){
    //change "/checkout" if your checkout page has a different url.
    header("Location: /checkout");
    die();
    } else {
     //your normal 404 page code here...
    } ?>
```